Neovim LSP: how to configure two servers running alongside each other for one filetype?
How do I configure two language servers (pylsp and Jedi-lsp) such that I can use Jedi for "Go to definition" code action and pylsp for everything else (formatting, autocompletion, etc.)?
The reason I want to do this is that Jedi specifically supports "Go to definition" for Pytest fixtures, but lacks pylsp formatting capabilities.
The current lua config uses nvim-lspconfig with the default setup options for both language servers:
require("lspconfig").pylsp.setup{
    settings = {
        pylsp = {
            plugins = {
                pycodestyle = {
                    enabled = true,
                },
                flake8 = {
                    enabled = true,
                },
                pyflakes = {
                    enabled = true,
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

require('lspconfig').jedi_language_server.setup{}

With this config Neovim only uses Jedi functionality, ignoring Pylsp (e.g. no formatting diagnostics are shown).
Is there a way to signal LSP client that I want to use Jedi for "Go to definition" code action, but Pylsp for everything else?
Initially went with Jedi for "Go to definition" for Pytest fixtures after reading this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/discussions/2117. If there is a better way to achieve this, I will be thankfull if you let me know.
Here is the LspInfo (nvim-lspconfig builtin) output:
 Language client log: /home/username/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
 Detected filetype:   python
 
 2 client(s) attached to this buffer: 
 
 Client: pylsp (id: 1, bufnr: [16])
    filetypes:       python
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  /home/username/projects/project
    cmd:             /home/username/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/pylsp
 
 Client: jedi_language_server (id: 2, bufnr: [16])
    filetypes:       python
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  /home/username/projects/project
    cmd:             /home/username/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/jedi-language-server
 
 1 active client(s) not attached to this buffer: 
 
 Client: lua_ls (id: 3, bufnr: [14, 33])
    filetypes:       lua
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  Running in single file mode.
    cmd:             /home/username/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/lua-language-server


Just want to make sure you have tried PyLSP by itself because it uses Jedi under the hood for definitions/completions so I would think that you wouldn't need to add Jedi to it.
